# Economic Effects of BIM

Tags: macroeconomics, poverty

The Boston Consulting Group has suggested BIM will save the Construction Industry $1.7 trillion /pa and increasing by  2025.

What effect will this have, if any, on social issues such as poverty, on global growth, improved quality of life and that sort of thing?

ps

BIM is Building Information Modelling and is used increasingly through the construction industry, building management and city modelling.
The paper that give these numbers is from the Boston Consulting Group paper on the Impact of BIM. See the link in the comment below.

The more specific question requested in the comments might be in social terms, what are the social benefits of reducing construction, energy and infrastructure costs over the long term. Would it result in improved living standards or does it get lost in the bank balances of the utilities and construction companies.

For what it is worth BIM is predicted to reduce GHG emissions by a significant (15%?) amount.

Comment: What is BIM? And ^^^ this guy must be either joking or a troll.

Comment: This is a rather open-ended question. It would improve notably, if you were to focus on some specific effect.

Comment: leeand00 is unto us. Quickly, let us make our escape with the 1%-mobil. Also, anyone who upvotes his comment does not get the daily $1,000 from our corporate overlords.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is referring to https://www.bcgperspectives.com/content/articles/engineered-products-project-business-digital-engineering-construction/